# arch linux not booting up after installation. Issue with grub

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, grub

I was currently trying to install arch linux as dual boot in my laptop (i3).

I was following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGhifbn6088

I completed the steps (everything installed normally) but during reboot I am getting this error

[image: error msg]

Here are the things I checked:

1. My windows is working fine and i am able to boot into it(not through grub).
2. Grub did not detect my windows boot manager but only my arch linux. Both arch and my windows are being installed in same ssd with two partitions (both uefi).
3. I had checked this command `ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/` and it did give me an output
4. I checked with this documentation https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide and most commands seem to be same except some optional commands

I have no idea how to fix this. I have formatted the os twice and the same error is happening.

Comment: So I assume the Arch installation medium booted fine? Maybe you forgot to install intel-ucode / amd-ucode, which happen to be required for your machine to boot? (Can't completely rule out that it is due to some new regression in the latest kernel though.)

Comment: Also, maybe you should see if booting with `nomodeset` makes a difference, just in case the error printed is actually irrelevant.

Comment: @TomYan Yes arch installation booted fine. I have installed intel-ucode by command `pacman -S intel-ucode`

Comment: What is nomodeset? Is it like an alternative to grub or addition to grub? I read the documentation but couldn't understand it

Comment: Just found out i forgot to update grub config. Now it is booting up without error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install `intel-ucode` package and add it to your grub config ?

If yes you can try to disable mce by adding `mce=off` to your grub config to see if you get another error message while trying to boot.

Comment: Yes i did install intel-ucode by `pacman install intel-ucode`

Comment: I will check the mce thing and update here

Comment: Update:- I forgot to add it to grub config. Now it booted up fine.
 Thank You for the help

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad your issue is fixed now.